# Manually resolve git merge conflicts with source tree

Tags: git, merge, conflict, manual, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using source tree on my mac for my git repositories. I merged two branches with a conflict in product.php. Now I have the following files:

```
product.php.BACKUP.43706.php
product.php.BASE.43706.php
product.php.LOCAL.43706.php
product.php.REMOTE.43706.php
```

I want to merge them with my favorite editor. For that I want to have a file with the following annotations and I thought this would be the native behavior of git.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:index.html
<div id="footer">contact : email.support@github.com</div>
=======
<div id="footer">
  please contact us at support@github.com
</div>
>>>>>>> iss53:index.html
```

found on: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

How could I get my merge file?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I found out, that the product.php is the file, I searched for. There are only the conflicts, but not the normal "merges". Is it possible to do that manually and get it in the conflict files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to deal with them. Just use `diff` command

```
git diff <first branch> <second branch> path/to/file
```

It will show you the difference and let you merge manually